# FileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog internal design

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

I had to use the [JavaFX's FileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) and I saw that the method `showOpenMultipleDialog` would return `null` when no `File` are selected.

Behavioural precision: one can only return from the dialog with the *Open* button when there's at least one file selected.

Does anybody know why such a choice for the return value whereas the absence of value can be modeled by an empty list in this case ?

Are the JavaFX developers in favor of `null` ? Or is there another technical reason ?

Comment: If the list is destined to be empty anyways, why bother creating it? I think I would have done the same thing too. Only create a list if the user chose atleast one file

Comment: Looks from the javadoc like null is supposed to signal cancellation, as opposed to selecting nothing. Maybe they foresaw the possibility of selecting nothing on certain platforms.